# npm install fails on Windows when better-sqlite3 is in the package.json

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, better-sqlite3

When executing "npm install" for my node application, I suddenly started getting the error:

> Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe"

[image]

I have narrowed it down to the following line in the `package.json` file under `dependencies`:

```
"better-sqlite3": "^4.1.4",
```

**What do I need to do or install so that I can load better-sqlite3 with npm on this Windows 10 64-bit machine?**

## Addendum:

1. I tried `npm install -g windows-build-tools` as administrator, but got the error:

> Could not install Visual Studio Build Tools.

[image]

2. I have Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition installed on this computer.
3. I have npm version 6.4.1.
4. Interestingly, a similar error occurs during `npm install` on linux, which can be avoided by removing the `"better-sqlite3": "^4.1.4"` line out of the `package.json` file:

[image]